# fb:comments Change the URL that's posted to facebook

Tags: facebook

I've added fb:comments to a page that sits in an IFrame in another page.  If the user clicks the "Post comment to my Facebook profile" the source URL posted on their Facebook wall is the IFrame source, and not the parent page.  Is there a way to change this URL in the fb:comment options?

I've tried the callbackurl & returnurl options, and neither of those work.  Also, setting opengraph meta tags on the IFrame source doesn't work either.

*edit: Code requested

```
<fb:comments canpost='false'></fb:comments>
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using with the `fb:comments`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the parent page url, set it in the href value of the comments plugin like this:

```
<fb:comments href="http://urlOfOuterPage.com"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you.  Weird that it's not in the official API docs (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/name/)  Can I ask you how you figured this out?

Comment: It is in the official documentation for fb:comments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/  (see the option for url to like)